# using nested case statements to return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

I'm trying to use case statements to have a value returned, depending on the conditions. Unfortunately I'm getting a string of syntax errors because I'm not completely familiar with how a case statement should be set up.

Basically, a user can belong to a single state (region), so in the user table is where the user's "state_id" is stored (53 could be Oregon for example). I had most of this working using if statements, but it was far too messy, so I was told "case" would be the better way to go. I also have a model "tax" which belongs_to a user and a user can have many of.

Prior to changing to using case, I was doing `if user.state_id == 53` for example, which was working, and then the conditions were `if self.income <= 10276` which also worked. Now with the case however, although slightly more refactored, I can't get it working.. (many syntax errors due to the evaluators `<=` and all the others.)

```
def provincial
case user.state_id
when 53
    case income
      when <= 10276
        return 0
      when 10277..37568
        return self.income * 0.0506
      when 37569..75138
        return ((self.income - 37568) * 0.077) + 1901
      when 75139..86268
        return ((self.income - 75138) * 0.105) + 4794
      when 86269..104754
        return ((self.income - 86268) * 0.1229) + 5963
      when > 104754
        return ((self.income - 104754) * 0.147) + 8235
    end

when 52
    case income
      when <= 17593
        return 0
      when > 17593
        return self.income * 0.10
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put the variable at the head of the case and then use a "dangling" inequality (an inequality where you only have an expression on one side). You would need the variable with the inequality, or you could use a `proc`.

So this `when` clause is fine:

```
when 10277..37568
  return self.income * 0.0506
```

But this one isn't:

```
when > 17593
  return self.income * 0.10
```

You can, however, replace it with this:

```
when proc {|n| n > 17593}
  return self.income * 0.10
```

This gets rid of the "dangling" inequality by using a `proc`. You might also be able to replace it with this (a little weird, but it works):

```
Inf = 1.0/0   # Assigns "infinity" to Inf

when 17593..Inf
  return self.income * 0.10
```

You could also move the variable to each `when`:

```
def provincial
  case user.state_id
    when 53
      case
        when income <= 10276
          return 0
        when (income >= 10277) and (income <= 37568)
          return self.income * 0.0506
        when (income >= 37569) and (income <= 75138)
          return ((self.income - 37568) * 0.077) + 1901
          ...
      end

    when 52
      case
        when income <= 17593
          return 0
        when income > 17593
          return self.income * 0.10
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Overall, in this situation, I think I like the `proc` best. :)

Note you can't mix, in the same case statement, the variable at the head of the case and the variable at the `when` clauses. So this is not valid:

```
case x
  when x < 3
    # do stuff
  when 5
    # do stuff
end
```